# fastest way to upload an xls file into a database

Tags: database, postgresql, xls

I have an xls file with ~60 sheets of data. I would like to move them into a database (postgres) such that each sheet's data is stored in a different table.

What is the fastest way of creating these tables? I don't care about naming or proper typing of columns. The columns could all be strings for that matter. I don't want to run 60 different csv uploads.

Comment: Which programming language are we talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the easiest tool for the job is OpenOffice. It has a wizard to easily create & populate a DB table from a spreadsheet.

Here's a walkthrough:

http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/Openoffice.org_with_SQL_Databases#Converting_Excel.2C_CSV.2C_..._to_PostgreSQL.2FMySQL.2F..._via_OO-Base